# Spark Streaming Windowing output

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am working on a spark streaming application, where I need to print min, max values of a json attribute,that attribute should print min, max on window of every 20 sec with the sliding window of 2 seconds.
Basically (for POC) I want to print min, max on the Spark UI of job group sparkContext.

```
SetJobGroup ("count-min-max", "count-min-max value of quality attribute").
```

This should display every 20 Sec on Spark UI display.

Below is my code I able to get min, max, count, but print is executed every 2 sec which is streaming batch interval not on window of 20 sec.

```
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkContext, Seconds(2))

val record = KafkaUtils.createStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, topicMap, StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER_2)
val lines=record.map(_._2)

      //val jsonCounts=lines.map { jsonRecord => parseJson(jsonRecord) }.map { x => x.mkString("\n") }.print

      val valueDtsream:DStream[Array[Double]]=lines.map { jsonRecord => parseJson(jsonRecord) }
                            .window(Seconds(20),Seconds(2))

      valueDtsream.foreachRDD
      {
         rdd => 
           if (!rdd.partitions.isEmpty)
           {
             val stats = rdd.flatMap(x => x)
             println(stats.count().toString()+"-"+stats.min().toString()+"-"+stats.max().toString)
           }
      }

      ssc.start()
      ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: What is  the question?

Comment: I want to print min,max,count at a window of every 20 secs, while my streaming batch time is 2 sec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are confused between `slideInterval` and `windowLength`. In `window(windowLength, slideInterval)`:

1. `windowLength` is the length of the window, meaning how many intervals of data the window should consider for the computation.
2. `slideInterval` is how many intervals the window moves after a window computation is completed.

If i understand your question correctly, you should edit it as : `.window(Seconds(x),Seconds(20))`.

Comment: I am new to this may you please help me with the explanation of window(windowLength, slideInterval) function; how it works

Comment: In your question you have specified it as printing "min,max,count at a window of every 20 secs", "while my streaming batch time is 2 sec". But what is your window Length?

Comment: vdep in my question I have mentioned I want to print min,max on every 20 sec window i.e. windowLength, but currently it is printing at every 2 sec which is my sliding interval.

Comment: No, the 20 sec is your `slideInterval` not `windowLength`.

Comment: for every 20 sec, you want to print min, max etc for the data in "how many past `streamingInterval`s"?. This defines the `windowLength`. You didn't mention that.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, as per api .window(Seconds(20),Seconds(2)) first parameter is windowLength and second is sliding interval, so windowLenght =20 and slidingInterval=2, please correct me if I am wrong.Yes but as per your explanation I need to configure sliding interval as 20 sec in order to print min,max every 20 sec.Hope my understanding is correct.

Comment: If you need to print min,... every `20 secs` for every past `20 secs` too, then its  `.window(Seconds(20),Seconds(20))`. If you haven't understood the difference between them, read the docs before proceeding.

Comment: I need to print every 20 sec for every past 2 sec

Comment: "print every 20 sec for every past 2 sec" doesn't make much sense because, at xth second you will find min, max for (x) & (x-1) second. So at 20th second you will compute for 19 & 20 second plus print them, but for all x <= 19 you WON'T print anything. In other words you are ignoring data from 0th second to 18th second for every `slideInterval` of 20 sec . Is this what you need?

Comment: @nilesh1212, consider accepting the answer if it is helpful.

Comment: Sure, It was helpful Thank you